# Is streaming possible through discord api

Tags: discord

So i have ready a lot about streaming through discord bots, especiall selfbots. Now my question is, does somebody have an idea if it is truly impossible to stream with a common discord bot or is there some hidden api feature that just isn't documented? I am asking since i saw, that a staff member of discord wrote that it would be really hard but never mentioned, that it was impossible.

Comment: Do you mean stream: audio, video via a (fake) webcam, or video via screenshare?

Comment: @LeoDog896 screenshare, because i would use it to stream videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, since the Discord API does not allow for bots to screenshare / enable the webcam. There simply is no option to do so.

It might be possible to do so via a selfbot, but this would be against the Discord TOS.